# how to access database kept in App_Data folder

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, sql-server-express, appdata

I am getting problem while I try to access MS-SQL database that is kept in "App_Data" folder.
My connection string in web.config file is-

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\CRMDb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

The Exception is-

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

Any relevant help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First things first: do you have SQL Express installed on your machine? If not you can get it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062) for free.

If you do have SQL Express installed, check if your SQL Express instance is running. If it's not running, open a command prompt ([as Administrator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)) and execute the following command:

```
net start mssql$sqlexpress
```